twillio validation always returns 403 (Node, Express)
my router file:
webhooksRouter.route("/twilio/webhook").post(
  twilio.webhook({ validate: shouldValidate, authToken }),
  urlencodedParser(),
 messagesController.twilioWebhook
);

For some reason it will not validate our request. The docs make it look easy, but it's not working.
